# What datatype to use when storing latitude and longitude data in DB2?

Tags: database, db2

When I need to save coordinates in DB2, what datatype would be most appropriate?

Comment: What about decfloat,it s better or worse than decimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a list of all Numeric Datatypes for DB2.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_numericdatatypes.dita

I would use a decimal or decimal float because they will :
1) Provide the ability to enter decimals
2) Give you a datatype that can hold large amounts ( more of the memory would be allocated to the datatype)